# Field names, querying Oracle database with PHP

Tags: php, sql, oracle

I have got this query below, to return a query from a database and display all of the information in a table, then query is user inputted.

Is there any way to get the field names to populate at the top of the table? Otherwise the first row is the raw data. I am struggling to find a way to do this, so any help would be appreciated.

```
<?php

if ($safeparam1 === null) {
}
else {

$stid = oci_parse($conn, $safeparam1);
$r = oci_execute($stid);

print '<p><input type="button" value="Clear Results" 
onclick=location.href=\'ul_move_query.php\';>  <input type="submit" 
value="Print Results">';
print '<table>';

while ($row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_RETURN_NULLS+OCI_ASSOC)) {
print '<tr>';
foreach ($row as $item) {
    print '<td>'.($item !== null ? htmlentities($item, ENT_QUOTES) : 
'').'</td>';
}
print '</tr>';
}
}


?>
```

Answer (score 1):

As you are fetching an associative array you can simply output the array keys as the header row:

```
$header = false; // a way to track if we've output the header.
while ($row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_RETURN_NULLS+OCI_ASSOC)) {
    if ($header == false) {
        // this is the first iteration of the while loop so output the header.
        print '<thead><tr>';
        foreach (array_keys($row) as $key) {
            print '<th>'.($key !== null ? htmlentities($key, ENT_QUOTES) :
                    '').'</th>';
        }
        print '</tr></thead>';

        $header = true; // make sure we don't output the header again.
    }

    // output all the data rows.
    print '<tr>';
    foreach ($row as $item) {
        print '<td>'.($item !== null ? htmlentities($item, ENT_QUOTES) :
                '').'</td>';
    }
    print '</tr>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can query `ALL_TAB_COLUMNS` table to get all columns of a specific table in Oracle.

```
select COLUMN_NAME from ALL_TAB_COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME='MYTABLE';
```

Comment: I think I was looking for something more php orientated, as that would have to be done per query correct?

Comment: @JamesPavett `php` alone can't do that. You have to query the table, if you are trying to retrieve columns from database.

Comment: @JamesPavett You need to execute above query using php only. There is NO OTHER WAY.

Comment: I get what you are saying, but I don't want all column names, just those that are being queried by the user.

Comment: Then, put the where condition.

Answer (score 0):

OCI8 has meta data calls like `oci_num_fields()` and `oci_field_name()`.  They can be used like:

```
$s = oci_parse($c, "select * from employees");
if (!$s) {
    $m = oci_error($c);
    trigger_error('Could not parse statement: '. $m['message'], E_USER_ERROR);
}
$r = oci_execute($s);
if (!$r) {
    $m = oci_error($s);
    trigger_error('Could not execute statement: '. $m['message'], E_USER_ERROR);
}

echo "<table border='1'>\n";
$ncols = oci_num_fields($s);
echo "<tr>\n";
for ($i = 1; $i <= $ncols; ++$i) {
    $colname = oci_field_name($s, $i);
    echo "  <th><b>".htmlspecialchars($colname,ENT_QUOTES|ENT_SUBSTITUTE)."</b></th>\n";
}
echo "</tr>\n";

while (($row = oci_fetch_array($s, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)) != false) {
    echo "<tr>\n";
    foreach ($row as $item) {
        echo "<td>";
        echo $item!==null?htmlspecialchars($item, ENT_QUOTES|ENT_SUBSTITUTE):"&nbsp;";
        echo "</td>\n";
    }
    echo "</tr>\n";
}
echo "</table>\n";
```