# Getting Column Name from SQL for PHP webpage

Tags: php, oracle11g

I am trying to build a PHP page. I have this section which fetches the results from Oracle Database without heading. Can anyone point me, how do i display the results along with column headers.
/ Fetch the results of the query

```
print "<table border='1'>\n";
while ($row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)) {
            print "<tr>\n";
    foreach ($row as $item) {
        print "    <td>" . ($item !== null ? htmlentities($item, ENT_QUOTES) : "&nbsp;") . "</td>\n";
    }
    print "</tr>\n";
}
print "</table>\n";
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46393562/field-names-querying-oracle-database-with-php

Comment: usually the headers are inside they keys, just point to the first row and use `array_keys`, then you have the header, echo it first, then proceed to  the fetching

Comment: I found the answer at the following post.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46393562/field-names-querying-oracle-database-with-php

Answer (score 0):

```
print "<table border='1'>\n";
$header = false;
while ($row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)) {

if($header == false) {
print '<thread><tr>';
foreach (array_keys($row) as $key) {
print '<th>'.($key !== null ? htmlentities($key, ENT_QUOTES) : '').'</th>'; }
print '</tr></thread>';
$header = true;
}

            print "<tr>\n";
    foreach ($row as $item) {
        print "    <td>" . ($item !== null ? htmlentities($item, ENT_QUOTES) : "&nbsp;") . "</td>\n";
    }
    print "</tr>\n";
}
print "</table>\n";
```